# Get to know the layer order in the flash timeline via as3 code

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

Is there any method with which I can get to know which of the two movieclips I'm using is lying above or below in the timeline 'layer' arrangement in flash.

what I'm asking is if have two movieclips 'a' and 'b'. One in layer 10 of timeline of flash professional and 'b' on layer 1. Will be able to change the index order using pure as3 code to visually keep the movieclip on the 10th layer on top of the movieclip on 1st layer??

Thank you.
Vishnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Edit]]

The attached method will not work if both target objects are leaf nodes in a shared parent.

---

The timeline children are always under whatever actionscript generated children are associated to the timeline class.

e.g.

If you have timeline X, which extends ClassA, and in Class A, you add children E, F, G, but timeline X contains layers B, C, D, each with a single symbol in each layer, with layer B at the bottom of the timeline, the following would be observed:

```
child 5: G
child 4: F
child 3: E
child 2: D
child 1: C
child 0: B
```

To expand on a felipemaia's answer, I've devised the following method to determine which movie clip lies absolutely above the other.  This has not been thoroughly tested, but should operate as a baseline for your development.

```
function selectAbove(obj1:DisplayObject, obj2:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
{

    var obj1_parentCount:int = parentCount(obj1);
    var obj2_parentCount:int = parentCount(obj2);

    var target:DisplayObject;
    var other:DisplayObject;

    if (obj1_parentCount > obj2_parentCount)
    {
        target = obj1;
        other = obj2;
    }
    else
    {
        target = obj2;
        other = obj1;
    }

    var container:DisplayObjectContainer =
        (target is DisplayObjectContainer) ? target as DisplayObjectContainer : target.parent ;

    var container_last:DisplayObjectContainer;

    var sharedParent:DisplayObjectContainer;

    while(container)
    {
        if(container.contains(other))
        {
            sharedParent = container;
            break;
        }

        container_last = container;
        container = container.parent;
    }

    if(!sharedParent)
    {
        throw new Error("An object does not maintain its parent in the display heirarchy!");
    }

    var ret:DisplayObject;

    if(container == other)
    {
        ret = target;
    }

    return container != other ?
        container.getChildIndex(container_last) < container.getChildIndex(other) ?
            other :
            target
        :
        target
    ;
}

function parentCount(obj:DisplayObject):int
{
    var ret:int = 0;

    while(obj)
    {
        ret++;
        obj = obj.parent;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This method will work for nested display hierarchies.  I have not tested this 100%, but initial cases completed as expected.

Best of luck!

Comment: man ! that was helpful ! :)) I mean, not just the code, but the concept. thanks a ton ! I'm planning to append this to my utility library !

Answer (score 1):

To verify which DisplayObject is on top, you're gonna have to compare their indexes with the [getChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex%28%29) method:

```
var mc1 : MovieClip;
var mc2 : MovieClip;

// THIS CODE ASSUMES THAT mc1 and mc2 HAVE THE SAME PARENT
var parentMC : MovieClip = MovieClip(mc1.parent);

var topmost : MovieClip = parentMC.getChildIndex(mc1) < parentMC.getChildIndex(mc2) ? mc1 : mc2;
```

The one who has the lowest index is the topmost one.

EDIT:

As long as the MovieClips have the same parent, you can manipulate the index of the objects with [swapChildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex%28%29), [swapChildrenAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29), and [setChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29). So to bring a MovieClip to the topmost front, you would do `MovieClip(parent).setChildIndex(this, 0);`

Comment: If you're asking how to switch the order of the MovieClips, yes, it's possible regardless of layers (as long as they're both on the same parent), view my edit.

Comment: this was not, what I was looking for, well, I have the idea of it now. Google told me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are layers in the context of ActionScript, but you can determine which instances of `DisplayObject` are further up using:

`DisplayObjectContainer` **.** [`getChildIndex()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex%28%29)

Comment: yea, I know this one.But what I'm asking is if have two movieclips 'a' and 'b'. One in layer 10 of timeline of flash professional and 'b' on layer 1. Will be able to change the index order using pure as3 code to visually keep the movieclip on the 10th layer on top of the movieclip on 1st layer??

Comment: @VishnuAjit A poor and incomplete question doesn't open my at the time valid answer for a downvote.